# Outer product from multiple `seq`s in bash

Tags: bash, sequence

From 3 sequences (for example): 
`seq 0 0.2 1`,
`seq 0 0.3 1.5`, 
`seq 0 0.5 1` 
I want to generate something like 
`0:0:0 0:0:0.5 0:0:1 0:0.3:0 0:0.3:0.5 0:0.3:1...`. They are in a format `a:b:c` where a is from the first sequence, b from the second, c from the third and all the combination show up once.

If these are integers and with unity step, I could use `{1..10}:{2..10}:{3..10}`, and it works nicely, but is there anyway to extend this brace function to noninterger and non unity step?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, `awk` is a better tool than `seq` for this job; it's POSIX-standardized, much faster at I/O than bash is, and you can run only one instance to generate all your output:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  for(a=0; a<=1; a+=0.2) {
    for(b=0; b<=1.5; b+=0.2) {
      for(c=0; c<=1; c+=0.5) {
        printf("%.1f:%.1f:%.1f\n", a, b, c);
      }
    }
  }
}' </dev/null
```

However, if for some reason you *really* want to use `seq`, nesting three [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loops will do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r a; do
  while read -r b; do
    while read -r c; do
      printf '%.1f:%.1f:%.1f\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
    done < <(seq 0 0.5 1)
  done < <(seq 0 0.3 1.5)
done < <(seq 0 0.2 1)
```

On my system, the `seq` version runs in ~0.3 seconds wall-clock, whereas the `awk` version takes ~0.01s.

Comment: `LC_NUMERIC=POSIX` or your sequences of floats may use a comma as decimal point.

Comment: ...though if running in a locale where a comma is *supposed* to be used as a decimal point, is that really a bug?

Comment: It is a bug if you are to use these floats into other commands that usually takes POSIX formatted floats and because varying your numeric format depending on system locale is a bad idea. Bash does not make a distinction between display formats and values format. When manipulating floats in a shell script, the universally supported locale format is `LC_NUMERIC=POSIX`. Any other locale format is a source of troubles. Unless you want to produce floating-point numbers for display purpose, then the user locale is appropriate.

Comment: `export LC_NUMERIC=en_DK.UTF-8; seq $(seq 0.2 0.3 1.0)` 
→ `seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘0,2’`
`export LC_NUMERIC=POSIX; seq $(seq 0.2 0.3 1.0)` → `0.2
0.7`

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I just think it's the user's job to decide if they care, since they're the entity that knows how the generated values will be consumed.

Comment: This is why, when someone manipulates floats in a Bash script, it is appropriate to remind of the LC_NUMERIC=POSIX precaution, or it is a mine-field of locale dependent and hard to trace-back bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel echo ::: $(seq 0 0.2 1) ::: $(seq 0 0.3 1.5) ::: $(seq 0 0.5 1) |
sed -z 'y/ \n/: /;s/\.0//g'
```

An alternative,using bash and sed:

```
echo {00..10..2}:{00..15..3}:{00..10..5} | sed 's/\B/./g;s/\.0//g'
```